# Tab indents showing in database, but not when echoed to page using php

Tags: php, mysql, formatting

I have enabled tab indents on a textarea, and when I look in phpmyadmin at my database, it shows the indents intact. However, when I try to echo it to the page using php, it does not preserve the tabs. It does preserve the line breaks. I am using nl2br().

I have done countless searches on it, but I keep getting questions about to to preserve tab indents when posting to the database. I am looking for the next step. Could someone please show me a technique or mark this as duplicate so I can find my answer?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT *
              FROM talk
              WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM talk ) ;";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
          {
  echo '<left><p>'.nl2br($row['post']).'</p></left> ';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Not relevant but you can use a simpler query: `select * from talk order by id desc limit 1`

Comment: Interesting. What are the advantages? Faster? Less bandwidth?

Comment: Faster. No subquery needed

Comment: Will do. For this project, query speed will be very important

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace to replace tab's with 3-5 nbsp's.

eg.

```
echo str_replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $yourstring);
```

Comment: Do I apply str_replace before or after nl2br?

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I use this. `$formatPost = str_replace("\t",'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$row['post']) ` Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Here's another attempt that has not worked. `$formatPost = $row['post']

           $finalPost = str_replace("\t",'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$formatPost) 
  echo '<left><p>'.nl2br($finalPost).'</p></left> ';`

Comment: Got it. Missing semicolon to last code. `$formatPost = $row['post'];

           $finalPost = str_replace("\t",'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$formatPost) ;
  echo '<left><p>'.nl2br($finalPost).'</p></left> ';`